# Playgrounds for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift-playground

Is it at all possible to have Xcode create a .playground file for Objective-C instead of Swift? Are there any available Xcode plugins that allow that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a very good library developed by [Krzysztof Zabłocki](http://merowing.info/2014/10/playgrounds-for-objective-c/) in Github entitled [KZPlayground](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/KZPlayground) that support both code in Playgrounds for Objective-C and Swift and a lot of cool features.

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 14):

You can quickly test code snippets using a test case in a new project. Just create a new project and go to the *Navigator* in the left pane and hit the *Test Navigator* button. Then follow [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html)

[image]

The setup code will look a little different than a swift playground, but it still allows you to prototype and play around.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If the only purpose is to test out Objective-C snippets, i would really recommend you an OS X command line Tool project.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are enough moving parts in a playground, and all of those would have to be reimplemented for Objective-C. Reliable playgrounds also depend on definite initialization which Objective-C does not have.

For instance consider:

```
var d: NSData // this is not initialized, so I can't use it
```

vs.

```
NSData *d; // this is also not initialized, but now I can use it
```

If I am the person storing the description of your NSData for the sidebar, now I know that I am not supposed to do

```
describe(d)
```

in the Swift case, but for the Objective-C case, I don't have equal knowledge and I run the risk of saying

```
[d description]; // even though d is a random pointer now.. oops, I just crashed!
```

In short, I don't think any such thing exists, and making one work would also involve some trickery

Comment: Calling `description` (or any method) to `nil` does not crash in Objective-C.

Comment: nil does not really worry me, it's uninitialized memory that does

Comment: The variable d will actually be initialized to nil if you use ARC. So no crash.